# String sort using CharacterSet order

Tags: swift, string, sorting

I am trying to alphabetically sort an array of non-English strings which contain a number of special Unicode characters.  I can create a CharacterSet sequence which contains the desired lexicographic sort order.

Is there an approach in Swift5 to performing this type of customized sort?
I believe I saw such a function some years back, but a pretty exhaustive search today failed to turn anything up.

Any pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: Presumably if the built in lexicographic ordering is unacceptable you would need to sort each pair of strings by comparing them character by character, using your character set sequence as a cosort guide. Cosorting is a well-established problem; typically you make a dictionary where the character is the key and its position in the order is the value, for rapid lookup via hashing.

Comment: I would normalize the text to Unicode _decomposed_ text: `é` as two characters: basic `e` followed by a zero-width diacritical mark `´`. This approves sorting a little, keeping Österreich (Austria) at the O. Linguistic locales would be better.

Comment: Thanks Joop for your suggestion, but the input strings have characters well out the Latin set, so just parsing diacritical marks etc is not a solution for this case.

Comment: Matt, this sounds like a generalized solution, if a bit inefficient.  I was imagining there was a little-known library method hiding somewhere ;)

Comment: Matt's answer is extremely efficient (if there were a cosorting method built-in, it would just do this under the covers). But this is definitely discouraged for Strings because it's very hard to do correctly for all locales; that's why Foundation provides powerful localized sorting that can handle many language- and culture-specific sorting rules (see Rob's answer below). But if that doesn't work, matt's cosorting answer is what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the illumination on the cohort algorithm!  Localization won't work here because of several non-Latin characters, some are Arabic, some are specialized Egyptian transliteration symbols all mixed in to act a 20 glyph alphabet.  Plus I need blank or space to sort to the end, not the beginning ;)

Comment: here is a simplified version of the lex order I need:"Ꜣ j i y Ꜥ w b p f m t n R r l h ḥ ḫ ẖ z s š q k g t ṯ d ḏ"

Comment: here is a simplified version of the lex order I need:"Ꜣ j i y Ꜥ w b p f m t n R r l h ḥ ḫ ẖ z s š q k g t ṯ d ḏ".    but the localized to ar_EG sort produces:  b d ḏ f g h ḥ ḫ ẖ (all the h chars sort into single group, not lex separated)  I (not i) k ḳ.  etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a simple implementation of matt's cosorting comment:

```swift
// You have `t` twice in your string; I've removed the first one.
let alphabet = "ꜢjiyꜤwbpfmnRrlhḥḫẖzsšqkgtṯdḏ "

// Map characters to their location in the string as integers
let order = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: zip(alphabet, 0...))

// Make the alphabet backwards as a test string
let string = alphabet.reversed()

// This sorts unknown characters at the end. Or you could throw instead.
let sorted = string.sorted { order[$0] ?? .max < order[$1] ?? .max }

print(sorted)
```

Comment: Very cool! I will check it out today!

Comment: You da Man Rob! Works perfectly when adapted to sorting by a property in my array of structs.  And your solution is > 50% smaller than mine!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than building your own “non-English” sorting, you might consider localized comparison. E.g.:

```swift
let strings = ["a", "á", "ä", "b", "c", "d", "e", "é", "f", "r", "s", "ß", "t"]

let result1 = strings.sorted()
print(result1) // ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "r", "s", "t", "ß", "á", "ä", "é"]

let result2 = strings.sorted {
    $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1) == .orderedAscending 
}
print(result2) // ["a", "á", "ä", "b", "c", "d", "e", "é", "f", "r", "s", "ß", "t"]

let locale = Locale(identifier: "sv")
let result3 = strings.sorted {
    $0.compare($1, options: .caseInsensitive, locale: locale) == .orderedAscending
}

print(result3) // ["a", "á", "b", "c", "d", "e", "é", "f", "r", "s", "ß", "t", "ä"]
```

---

And a non-Latin example:

```swift
let strings = ["あ", "か", "さ", "た", "い", "き", "し", "ち", "う", "く", "す", "つ", "ア", "カ", "サ", "タ", "イ", "キ", "シ", "チ", "ウ", "ク", "ス", "ツ", "が", "ぎ"]

let result4 = strings.sorted {
    $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1) == .orderedAscending 
}
print(result4) // ["あ", "ア", "い", "イ", "う", "ウ", "か", "カ", "が", "き", "キ", "ぎ", "く", "ク", "さ", "サ", "し", "シ", "す", "ス", "た", "タ", "ち", "チ", "つ", "ツ"]
```